# Parse PHP variables to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Can't get the php variables to populate the javascript code

I tried the code below.

```
<?php
$destination="PAR";
$destination_name="Paris";
?>
<script async src="//www.travelpayouts.com/weedle/widget.js?
width=260px&marker=235474&host=search.jetradar.com&locale=en&currency=
usd&powered_by=false&destination="<?php echo $destination ? 
>";&destination_name="<?php echo $destination_name ?>";" 
charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

The result doesn't show the right destination

Comment: did you try escaping the double quotes or replacing them with single quotes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need quotes around GET parameters.

```
<?php
$destination="PAR";
$destination_name="Paris";
?>
<script async src="//www.travelpayouts.com/weedle/widget.js?
width=260px&marker=235474&host=search.jetradar.com&locale=en&currency=
usd&powered_by=false&destination=<?php echo $destination ?>&destination_name=<?php echo $destination_name ?>" 
charset="UTF-8"></script>
```